# AdvanceFilter giving Error 1004, "missing or invalid field name"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm filtering some data, but I'm receiving the above error. The Sub code is as follows:

```
Sub FilterAndCopy(ByRef RegisterData As Range, ByVal Column As String, ByRef Criteria As Variant)

Dim rngCriteria As Range, ErrLastCell As Range, ErrLastRow As Range
Dim WS_REG As Worksheet, WS_ERROR As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set WS_REG = Sheets("REGISTER")
Set WS_ERROR = Sheets("ERROR")
Set rngCriteria = WS_ERROR.Range("AA1:AE2")

Set rngCriteria = rngCriteria.Resize(2, UBound(Criteria, 1))
For i = 1 To UBound(Criteria, 1)
   rngCriteria(1, i) = Column
   rngCriteria(2, i) = Criteria(i)
Next i

Set ErrLastCell = GetLastCell(WS_ERROR.UsedRange)
Set ErrLastRow = WS_ERROR.Range(ErrLastCell.row & ":" & ErrLastCell.row)

        With RegisterData
            .AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngCriteria, ErrLastRow.Offset(1, 0)
        End With

Set ErrLastCell = GetLastCell(WS_ERROR.UsedRange)
WS_ERROR.Range("W" & ErrLastRow.row + 1 & ":W" & ErrLastCell.row).value = "Zone Id not valid"
rngCriteria.Clear
Rows(ErrLastRow.row + 1).Delete
DoEvents

End Sub
```

The Sub is called from a parent one, that sends an array with the criteria and the column, as follows:

```
Dim Criteria1 As Variant, Criteria2 As Variant, Criteria3 As Variant, Criteria4 As Variant, Criteria5 As Variant
Dim Column1 As String, Column2 As String, Column3 As String, Column4 As String, Column5 As String
Criteria2 = Array("<>Z1", "<>Z2", "<>Z0")
Criteria4 = Array("<>Ex d", "<>Ex e", "<>Ex n", "<>Ex p", "<>Ex i")
Column2 = "Column 8"


Call FilterAndCopy(RegisterData, Column2, Criteria2)
```

RegisterData comes from a previous calculation, by reference, and includes the data and the headers (tested doing RegisterData.Select).

I've Checked the Variables, headers and everything looks fine to me, as per the images below. Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I've tried the same sub, standalone, and works. Here is the code:

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

Dim rngCriteria As Range, ErrLastCell As Range, ErrLastRow As Range
Dim WS_REG As Worksheet, WS_ERROR As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set WS_REG = Sheets("REGISTER")
Set WS_ERROR = Sheets("ERROR")
Set rngCriteria = WS_ERROR.Range("AA1:AE2")

Dim RegisterData
Set RegisterData = WS_REG.Range("A6:W5912")

Dim Criteria As Variant
Criteria = Array("<>Z1", "<>Z2", "<>Z0")
Dim Column As String
Column = "Column 8"


Set rngCriteria = rngCriteria.Resize(2, UBound(Criteria, 1))
For i = 1 To UBound(Criteria, 1)
   rngCriteria(1, i) = Column
   rngCriteria(2, i) = Criteria(i)
Next i

Set ErrLastCell = GetLastCell(WS_ERROR.UsedRange)
Set ErrLastRow = ErrLastCell.EntireRow

        With RegisterData
            .Select
            .AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, rngCriteria ', ErrLastRow.Offset(1, 0)
        End With

Set ErrLastCell = GetLastCell(WS_ERROR.UsedRange)

'WS_ERROR.Range("W" & ErrLastRow.row + 1 & ":W" & ErrLastCell.row).value = "Zone Id not valid"
'rngCriteria.Clear
'Rows(ErrLastRow.row + 1).Delete
DoEvents

End Sub
```

So, I'm I missing something? Can be an issue when passing the variables?

[Locals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmRAA.png)

[Watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB1ar.png)

Comment: Of the top of my head, `"Column 8"` seems off.

Comment: Well, I should have Named the variables as ColumnCriteria to avoid confusion. don't know if you mean that

Comment: What is "column 8" supposed to represent / do? See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter). It looks... off.

Comment: Side note: `Set ErrLastRow = WS_ERROR.Range(ErrLastCell.row & ":" & ErrLastCell.row)` can just be `Set ErrLastRow = ErrLastCell.EntireRow`.

Comment: Column 8 refers to the headers (I named them Column 1 to 30), as the autofilter checks the headers to check the criteria in that column. I create a range for the autofilter, with the column to check in the top and the criterias below, as I need to use ANDs to exclude the values that don't meet the criterias.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Found the issue. For some reason, I had to pass the "Column" variable as byRef instead as byVal